# Interdependent and soft pod topology spread constraints

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling

This is a variation of my previous question:

[Spreading pods evenly across nodes within a topology domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975322/spreading-pods-evenly-across-nodes-within-a-topology-domain)

Suppose I have the same cluster:

```
zoneA:
- node1: 8 CPU
zoneB:
- node2: 4 CPU
- node3: 4 CPU
```

If I wanted to guarantee (hard constraint) an even spread of pods across zoneA and zoneB while trying (soft constraint) to evenly spread pods within zoneB, I could specify 2 pod topology spread constraints:

```yaml
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        app: foo
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
    whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        app: foo
```

However, say I wanted to make both of the constraints soft but also interdependent. In other words, I want the scheduler to try to "spread evenly across zoneA and zoneB" AND "spread evenly within zoneB", but if it can't do both, ScheduleAnyway.

I don't believe I could simply set the zone constraint to ScheduleAnyway since the scheduler would then have the freedom to place 10 pods like the following:

```
node1 (8 CPU): 4 pods
node2 (4 CPU): 3 pods
node3 (4 CPU): 3 pods
```

instead of the desired placement:

```
node1 (8 CPU): 5 pods
node2 (4 CPU): 3 pods
node3 (4 CPU): 2 pods
```

Is there any way to express that I want both of these constraints to be interdependent while still being soft?